# Azure App service function fails after a month working correctly

Tags: azure-functions

My App service Azure http trigger functions have stopped working correctly since July 14th. They only work inside of Azure test tool portal. If I call the same http trigger function from outside Azure (browser or web App) it returns a 500 error. It receive the call but seems that it does not receive the body contents of the post.
I 've had it running without any problem. The same Azure functions for months and suddenly form July 14th they started to fail.

Comment: Can you add the information from the log file on the server? What are the configurations for the function and what language are you using?

Comment: The function reads a "id" form the body and searches the "id" on a Cosmos DB. The cosmos DB gives the error "Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTrigger1 The given key 'id' was not present in the dictionary.".

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has detected the issue in your server and is fixing it.